# Jenkins logroate is failing

Tags: jenkins

I have a jenkins instance where the logrotate is configured to rotate files above 4096K.But the logfile is currently 1.4GB. logroate status shows that the it has run today. Is there a way to check why its failing?No errors observed in jenkins.lob about logroate and the logrotate was functioning correctly before.

```
/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log /var/log/jenkins/access_log {
    compress
    dateext
    maxage 365
    rotate 99
    size=+4096k
    notifempty
    missingok
    create 644
    copytruncate
}

logrotate state -- version 2
"/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log" 2019-12-9-3:21:1
```

Comment: I am no expert in logrotate, but from all of the examples I have seen, none have a `+` in the example (and I am not sure about the `=` either). Have you tried `size=4096k` or `size 4096k`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I figured out that there is no enough space on the FS for logrotate to place the compressed file. I got this by running logrotate command with -v option.
https://qamag.net/stop-that-huge-jenkins-log/

Comment: Ok, glad you got it solved.